# Range-based for loop with abstract class as declaration C++

Tags: c++, loops, class

I want to iterate through a list of an abstract class `list<abstract>` using a for loop.

Here's my code:

```
class Component {
    protected:
        string name;
        int price;

    public:
        Component(string name, int price): name(name), price(price){};

        virtual int getPrice() =0;
};

class Composite : public Component {
    list<Component> components;

    public:
        int getPrice() {
            for(Component comp : components) {
                return comp.getPrice();   
            } 
        }   
};

class Leaf : public Component {
    public:
        int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
};
```

But I get an error; cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Component'. This error makes sense, as abstract types can't be instantiated.

Comment: Ok, you understand that abstract types can't be instantiated. So how do you expect to instantiate any member of your `std::list`, which is abstract? The list contains abstract objects. So they have to exist, in the list. But they can't. They're abstract. I have a hunch that you have a Java background, because you expect it to work like that. It won't, not in C++.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to know how to do range-based loop or how to create list of abstract object? Also, you haven't not tell on which line you got the error! Thus because of the title, I was thinking that you want to understand why the ranged-based loop was not compiling.

Comment: Haha haven't touched Java, but was following an example in it. An answer suggests to use pointers of type abstract class which makes sense (same method was used on cplusplus iirc.

Comment: @RsFps: Java treats objects and pointers to objects as almost the same, C++ doesn't. This is one of those cases where you will notice that.

Comment: What is the type of ```comp```? Isn't it some iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some problems:

You declare `virtual int getPrice() = 0;` and this makes your `Component` pure virtual -> you CANNOT instantiate an object of it -> `list<Component> components;` does NOT make sense to appear. Please consider to use `list<Component*>` (or smart-pointer) instead!

Range-based for loop:

```
for(Component comp : components) {
    return comp.getPrice();   
}
```

Suppose you have updated your list to `list<Component*>` then the for loop could be:

```
for(auto& comp : components) {
    return comp->getPrice();   
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing ```auto&``` in the for loop? Shouldn't it be ```Component*```?

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out with no luck; but I don't understand why we're using ```auto&``` instead of ```auto```. Can you please elaborate as to why we are using the reference? Thanks!

Comment: @RsFps As you have caught it, `auto &` means we want the `comp` reference to each element of the list -- which has the advantage of NOT being copied. If we, however, use `auto` then each element of the list will be first copied to `comp` -- which is usually more costly compared with just making reference to. However, as `Component*` is already pointer type so the advantage won't be significant.

Answer (score 2):

`list<Component>` means the `list` can only contain objects whose type is exactly `Component`. It cannot contain objects of some other type (even if derived from Component).

Since it is not possible to create (complete) objects of type `Component`, this list is not usable.

To create a list which can store any object having `Component` as a base class, the list items must be stored by reference. But then you have to think about lifetime management of the objects in the list.

---

One way to do this would be:

```
std::list< std::shared_ptr<Component> > components;
```

and the loop might be:

```
for(auto& comp : components) {
     return comp->getPrice();   
}
```

(although why you're using a loop when you always exit on the first item is another question).

There are other options available too which represent different ownership semantics.  I would recommend reading a guide on smart pointers in C++ for further understanding of this topic.

Comment: I've read up a bit about smart pointers. Don't understand their use in this case. Won't the pointers be deleted when going out of scope anyway? I will continue to investigate smart pointers, but so far all I'm  understanding is that they're a way of automatically deleting pointers that reference memory created with the new keyword.

Comment: @RsFps In this case the benefit is that you can have a list of them, where the pointers point to objects of different types (with a common base class).  The lifetime management is an added bonus. BTW you can use `make_shared` rather than `new` to create the objects.

Comment: Are you talking about pointers in general? I'm that case yes, I know why they need to be used here. I was talking about smart pointers. What's the point of having a list of Component smart pointers as opposed to regular Component pointers?

Comment: @RsFps Then the objects will be deleted when they are no longer being referenced

Comment: Isn't that what we want? The for loop isn't being "called" (sorry if that's the wrong term). I changed it and it's skipping it.

Comment: Oh do you mean that after referencing in the for loop, they will be destroyed?

Comment: Yes that's what we want (the objects to be deleted when they are no longer referenced), which is why I suggested using the smart pointer.

Comment: Why are we using a reference in the for loop? Why not just say "auto comp"?

Comment: @RsFps to avoid making a copy of the object in the container

Comment: Can we use "Component* comp : components"?

Comment: @RsFps No , since the elements are not of type `Component*` nor implicitly convertible to

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Isn't the list ```list<Component*>```?

Comment: @RsFps my suggestion was to use `std::list< std::shared_ptr<Component> >`

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate that you want a reference:

```
for(Component & comp : components)
```

Or simply

```
for(auto & comp : components)
```

If you want (or need), you can also add `const` modifier.

```
for(const Component & comp : components)
```

**Note**

While my anser might be incomplete, it does explain the error reported in the question. As other have not reported, it make no sense to create a list of abstract object by value.

However the question was specific about the problem related to the loop too. As such, I think that my answer was adequate given the question.

Comment: I tried that, and get these errors: 8:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Component':
16:21: note:  virtual int Component::getPrice()

Comment: That's nice, but this is too little, too late. The shown code will be unable to add any actual values to the list, because of object slicing, and there will never be anything to iterate over.

Comment: This is not the problem. The code attempts to create a `list<Component>`.

Comment: How do I get around that?

Comment: @RsFps My response is about the error you reported. I haven't analysis you whole code.

Comment: @PeteBecker The question started with **Range-based for loop** so my answer was specifically about why the range based loop was not working. Also, OP didn't tell on which line he got the error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In it question title, OP ask about range-based for loop. So I think it was perfectly right to only answer about that specific point.

Comment: Why are we using a reference in the for loop? Can't we use a pointer?

Comment: @RsFps You can use pointer only when the for loop returns pointers (think array of pointer vs array of object).

Comment: @Phil1979 but doesn't the list consist of Component*?

Comment: The declaration *(in the question)* is `list<Component> components;` so it is a list of objects, not pointers. A list of pointers would be `list<Component *> components;`.

Comment: Sorry I assumed we have updated the list to list<Component*>

Comment: Well, the problem is that the question was misleading as the error has nothing to do with range based loop... but you start the description with **I want to iterate...**. Thus I have focused only on the problem of the loop that cannot make copy but not about problem with the list itself.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; in the past couple of comments I was talking about why the loop is using ```auto&```.